# How to run the same VBA code on multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that runs until a condition is met in Row 8.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim i As Double
    Dim x As Double

    t = Range("K3").Value
    i = Range("C8").Value
    x = Range("E8").Value
    b = Range("B8").Value
    
    Do Until i > (x + t)
        i = i + 0.2
    Loop
      
    i = i - 0.2 - b
    
    Range("G8").Value = i

End Sub
```

This does what I require for Row 8 but I need to run on multiple rows. The only value that will be static is cell 'K3'.

i.e.: Once it is done on row 8, run on Row 9 ('C9','E9','B9','G9') and so on. Either this will need to run until row 500, or a count of rows entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a whole heap of people here that will give you a much more complete answer but I'm here to answer your direct question.

If you need to apply other enhancements then that can come with other questions.  This will help you learn and progress without throwing a heap of code at you that you're not sure of.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim x As Double
    Dim lngRow As Long
    
    t = Range("K3").Value
    
    For lngRow = 8 To 500
        i = Range("C" & lngRow).Value
        x = Range("E" & lngRow).Value
        b = Range("B" & lngRow).Value
        
        Do Until i > (x + t)
            i = i + 0.2
        Loop
          
        i = i - 0.2 - b
            
        Range("G" & lngRow).Value = i
    Next
End Sub
```

That's a simple way to loop through each row.

Considerations you should make on performance are to do with looping, updating cells constantly, calculations and events when updating cells, etc.

But that answers your question.

Comment: Another consideration would be to make sure that the ranges are all qualified with their parent sheets.  This will avoid problems in the future.

Comment: @ScottCraner, good point ...!

Comment: Thank you Skin, I appreciate your answer, this looks like it will do exactly what I am trying to do at the moment. Looking forward to learning more.

Comment: @BradMorg, cool man and keep at it.  It's a good, fun, portable space to code in.  Very powerful too.